# Array inside function not working?

Tags: php, class

PHP CODE

```
class XXX{
public function ggGet($str){
    return gGet($str); // This is ok working gGet is global function
}
public static $Array = array ( "value" => $this->ggGet("email")); // This code is error Why?

}
```

I must use a function in array in class.

I see this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/

What must i do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class XXX{

   $MyArray = array(); 

   public function __construct(){
      $this->MyArray["value"] = $this->ggGet("email");
   }

   public function ggGet($str){
       return gGet($str); 
   }

}
```

Use __construct() every time you need to start values in a var inside a class.